# Unable to assign value of counter variable to nft id

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, nft

```
function _mint(string memory _name, bool _isOnSale, uint _price) public{
    MyNft storage nft = fetchNft[_name];
    require(!nft.exists, "The Nft already Exists");        
    uint counter;
    nft.id += counter++;
    nft.name = _name;
    nft.isOnSale = _isOnSale;
    nft.owner = msg.sender;
    nft.price = _price * 1 ether;
    nft.exists = true;
    counter = nft.id;

 }
```

In the above function, I'm trying to assign the value of the counter variable to nft.id, However the value that is assigned to nft.id always remains 0, No matter how many times I execute the mint function.

Please help me in knowing the reason behind this issue and how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `counter` variable is declared inside the `_mint(string memory _name, bool _isOnSale, uint _price)` function itself, so every time you call the function it'll be declared as new and will contain the default value which is `0`.
You need to declare it outside the function in order to track the number of NFTs minted.

Also, I wonder why are you assigning the ID like `nft.id += counter++;` I mean, why are you using `+=` while assigning?

If the NFT is new, which will be the case always if the flow reaches that line, `nft.id` must be `0`, so using `+=` will have no difference than using only `=`.

And about using `post-fix` and `pre-fix` operators, if you just declare the counter variable like `uint counter;`, and use it to assign the id like `nft.id = counter++;`, for the first NFT it'll assign id as `0`. The reason is, `post-fix` first assigns the value to the variable and then increments the value of the variable it has been used with.

You can either declare the counter variable with initial value 1 (`uint counter = 1;`) or use `pre-fix` while assigning the value like `nft.id = ++counter;`. Because the `pre-fix` operator first increments the variable's value and then stores it to the variable it is being assigned to.

I've **not tested it**, but your updated code may look something like this-

```
uint counter;

function _mint(string memory _name, bool _isOnSale, uint _price) public{
    MyNft storage nft = fetchNft[_name];
    require(!nft.exists, "The Nft already Exists");        
    nft.id = ++counter;
    nft.name = _name;
    nft.isOnSale = _isOnSale;
    nft.owner = msg.sender;
    nft.price = _price * 1 ether;
    nft.exists = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `post-fix` increment to assign id.

> a++ and a-- are equivalent to a += 1 / a -= 1 but the expression
> itself still has the previous value of a. In contrast, --a and ++a
> have the same effect on a but return the value after the change.

Try using, `counter+=1` before `nft.id += counter` or use `nft.id += ++counter`